# Why is my velocity increasing instead of decreasing?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics

I am learning to use point effectors in Unity!

Now I have a sprite that is being effected by this point effector and it all works fine alone. I have introduced the following code to give the player the ability to break free from the pull of the point effector as follows:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) MoveOutwards();
}


void MoveOutwards() {
    Vector2 force = directionFromCentre () * 10f;
    rb2D.AddForce (force);
}

Vector2 directionFromCentre() {
    Vector2 dir = new Vector2 (transform.position.x,transform.position.y);
    dir /= dir.magnitude;
    return (dir);
}
```

To be noted the point effector is located at (0,0,0).
When my point effector is having a magnitude of **-5f** the player is able to move outwards. However when I put the magnitude of **-20f** he is not moving outwards, infact he is speeding up the motion towards the centre of the point effector!

I can't seem to understand why!? The players should actually slow down from moving towards the point effector.

Other details regarding the point effector:
[image]

Comment: To be clear: are you saying that when trying to move away, by pressing space, it instead accelerates towards the point effector *faster* than if you didn’t press space?

Comment: Also, as a side note, `directionFromCenter()` could be replaced with `transform.position.normalized`